# How to convert the image received with django request FILES into pdf

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I saw many answers, but it was hard to find the answer I wanted.
I don't want to find files locally and save them locally.
I want to receive the image with request FILES and convert it directly into pdf.
I'd appreciate it if you could give me an answer.

Finally, I want to upload it to s3.

```py
def create(self):
    file = self.request.FILES.get('file', None)
    # image -> pdf
    # local save() No.
    ...
```

Is there something wrong with the settings?

```py
# settings.py
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```